# Use default JsonSerializer but with snake case field names

Tags: jackson

I have a class which should be serialized to `snake_case` JSON.

General approach to this problem as far as I know, is to annotate the given class like this:

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class MyClass
```

This would be sufficient for a simple class with primitive field names. However in my case, `MyClass` contains fields which are class-types. Therefore, on the output, fields within those classes are serialized as `camelCase` (because I cannot annotate those, since they are used in other parts of the system as camelCase-JSONs).

At the moment, I am attempting to create a custom serializer, like this:

Class to be serialized with snake_case:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = SnakeCaseSerializer.class)
class MyClass { /* ... */ }
```

Custom serializer:

```
public class SnakeCaseSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MyClass> {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper;

    static {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategies.SNAKE_CASE);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(final MyClass value,
                          final JsonGenerator gen,
                          final SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
       // Put serialization logic here...
    }

}
```

I have attempted, as suggested by other answers on StackOverflow, to use a custom `ObjectMapper` with `propertyNamingStrategy=SNAKE_CASE`, however I haven't found a way to get an instance of the default `JsonSerializer` which would output a snake_case-formatted JSON file.

Under the assumption that classes which are used as fields in `MyClass` cannot be annotated or modified in any way, what would be the correct solution to my problem?

As a side note, the remaining parts of the project use default `camelCase` serialization, so setting `snake_case` on project-level settings is not suitable.

Comment: Would using `@JsonProperty("field_name")` on each field be an acceptable solution, or is that too static for your use case?

Comment: @jacob Unfortunately, that would mean annotating all classes which exist as fields within `MyClass`, which isn't acceptable, as they have to be used elsewhere as `camelCase`...